# Product of a discrete and absolutely continuous random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have the independent random variables $U \sim e(1)$ and $V \sim po(2)$. We define the variable $Y=UV$. I want to prove that Y is not absolutely continuous. The only hint I have recieved is that I can use the property that for an absolutely continuous random variable, $P(X=x)=0, \forall x$. However, this doesn't help me when I have no idea how the product of these variables work! Only one of them has a probability mass function, and only one of them has a probability density function.

Comment: Hint on your hint: consider x=0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Hint**: 
$$
\{Y=0\}\supseteq\{V=0\}.
$$

Comment: That is pretty obvious, but I don't see what it implies.

Comment: So what is $P(Y=0)$ larger than?

Comment: Larger than or equal to $e^{-2}$, I'm assuming, meaning we don't have absolute continuity. That does make sense, I'd just been looking into ways of determining the joint probability distribution and not thinking in that direction at all.

Comment: Exactly. ${}{}$